# Subtitle and title at bottom of highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Is there a clean way of putting both title and subtitle at the bottom of a highcharts chart ?

When setting both `verticalAlign` to `bottom`, the subtitle overlaps the title, and adding a `y` offset makes one or the other either overflow out of the chart box, or overlap with the chart in itself.

Default behavior:

[image]

Adding 20px offset to subtitle:

[image]

I wish the chart would simply make space for both to be at the bottom, since total height and width is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a `marginBottom` to your chart to make space for the titles. Further a negative y-attribute moves the titles upwards.

Something like the following should solve your problems:

```
chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    marginBottom: 80
},
title: {
    text: 'Main title',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    y: -30
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'My subtitle',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    y: -10
}
```

As also illustrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Loxos/zkrrof39/).